# Join with two conditions in R

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, left-join

I want to perform a join in RStudio with 2 conditions. My goal is to **replicate a SQL query** like the following, but **in R language**:

```
SELECT
   ticket_id,
   sum(time_to_close)
FROM helpdesk_ticket ht
LEFT JOIN dim_date dd ON ht.create_date <= dd.formatted_date AND dd.formatted_date <= ht.closed_date
GROUP BY 1
```

Assuming that helpdesk_ticket and dim_date are two R dataframes, this is what I have tried, but it returns an **error in the left_join**:

```
result <- helpdesk_ticket %>%
  left_join(dim_date, by = c("create_date" <= "formatted_date", "formatted_date" <= "closed_date")) %>%
  group_by(ticket_id) %>%
  summarise(time_to_close = sum(time_to_close))
```

Comment: Instead of having us assume the datasets, could you edit your question to provide small reproducible samples of each dataset and the desired outcome? Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the SQL query uses an interval join with `<=` and `>=` operators rather than equality `=`, consider [**`dplyr::join_by`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html) to precompute the inequality join to be used in `left_join`.

```r
by <- join_by(
  create_date <= formatted_date, 
  closed_date >= formatted_date,
) 

result <- helpdesk_ticket %>%
  left_join(dim_date, by) %>%
  group_by(ticket_id) %>%
  summarise(time_to_close = sum(time_to_close))
```

Alternatively, if both or either data sets are not too large for cartesian product, consider a `cross_join` followed by a `filter`:

```r
result <- helpdesk_ticket %>%
  cross_join(dim_date) %>%
  filter(
    create_date <= formatted_date, 
    closed_date >= formatted_date
  )
```

Comment: perhaps `by <- join_by(between(formatted_date, create_date, closed_date))`?